# Is there a Java/Swing implementation of "compound menu item" as in Chrome?

Tags: java, swing, button, menu

First of all, is there an "official" name for menu items like Edit and Zoom in the Chrome browser?

[image]

Is there an existing Swing implementation?

On the surface it could be another "I can do it in a weekend" thing, but getting the button to look good for all LAFs would be difficult as always, since the default button is obviuosly too "boxy" for these "inline" buttons (and the "spinner lite" for Zoom). And getting text/accelerator alignment correct could be next to impossible.

Comment: Chrome the browser?  What items are you talking about?  Creating buttons that work with all LAFs should not be an issue.  Can you expand upon your question?

Comment: See also [How to Write a Custom Swing Component](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/22/how-to-write-custom-swing-component.html).

Comment: @jzd: yes the browser. Question is updated. I'm asking if someone already did the work (write the custom JMenuItem) that I'm too lazy to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing the point of a LAF.  If a look and feel contains boxy buttons then you should let it define the borders and look of the button.  The only way you can let something work for all look and feels is not to mess with the defaults.

However, if you want something to look a specific way, you will need to create a custom component, that possibly uses defaults colors for a menu or button, or preset values.

Comment: What he was saying is that the buttons provided by a LAF are designed to look good on a dialog box surface, not on a menu item.

Comment: @Random832: thanks for speaking my mind. Yes it's easy to replace the default button border, but still not trivial (e.g. rounded corners for only first and last buttons) and you may want slightly different borders for different LAF (I don't know what Chrome looks like on other OSs than Windows XP).

Answer (score 1):

There is a partial Swing implementation here:

http://code.google.com/p/jbuttonmenuitem/

It can handle the Edit menu items, but probably not the Zoom.